# The specified solution configuration is invalid

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

Using .NET Core 7 (SDK 7.0.402), I am running the command:

```
dotnet build -c development
```

But I get this error:

> Error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "development|Any CPU" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties

This command didn't throw any error a few days ago ...

The project file includes the `development` configuration:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">development</Configuration>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'development'">
    <ConfigurationGroup>Debug</ConfigurationGroup>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'staging'">
    <ConfigurationGroup>Release</ConfigurationGroup>
  </PropertyGroup> 

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'production'">
    <ConfigurationGroup>Release</ConfigurationGroup>
  </PropertyGroup> 

</Project>
```

What am I missing? Did something change in msbuild?

Comment: Was a solution file (.sln) added to the directory?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your problem and I solved it by recreating the configuration for development, staging, and production in `Configuration Manager`.

**Note:** Directly copying the settings in `.csproj` does not seem to take effect in VS2022, and the error will still occur.

**Step 1: Right-click the Solution, and find the Configuration Mansger...**

[image]

**Step 2: Click <New...>, and create the 1,2,3 in my screenshot.**

[image]

**Step 3: Then run the command `dotnet build -c development`.**

[image]